# Nodes without any value not recognised in XML

Tags: perl, xpath, libxml2

My XML:

```
<mi>
<mt>CPU </mt>
<mv>
      <moid> </moid>
       <r>1</r>
</mv>
<mv>
      <moid> TT </moid>
       <r>2</r>
</mv>
</mi>
```

My requirement is simple 
Only when `mt` is CPU then update the `r` node to 20 where `moid` is empty and update `r` to 30 where `moid` is TT.

So my output should

```
<moid></moid>
<r>20</r>
<moid>TT</moid>
<r>30</r>
```

My code is :

```
my $rng="" or TT as the case may be:
$qry="//*[name()='mi'][*[name()='mt'][contains(text() , 'CPU')]]/*[name()='mv']";
```

NODE:

```
foreach my $vnode ($conn->findnodes($qry)) {
    CHILD: foreach my $p ($vnode->getChildnodes) {
if (ref($p)=~'Element' && $p->nodeName eq "moid" && $p->textContent =~ /$rng/  && 
!$moidFound) {
    $moidFound=1; 
            next CHILD; 
        }
        elsif {
            //some code to modify the < r> node;
            last NODE;
        }
    }
 }
```

---

My code works well when I have the `moid` node value as TT, but it does not work when `moid` node is empty. It is not able to recognize the `moid` node at all when its empty?

Is there anything silly I am doing?

Comment: Please fix the formatting ...

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easily handled using XPaths and [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aTwig).

For example of xpaths, check out [`xpath examples`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $t= XML::Twig->new( 
    twig_handlers => {
        q{//mi[string(mt) =~ /^\s*CPU\s*$/]/mv[string(moid) =~ /^\s*$/]/r} => sub { $_->set_text('20') },
        q{//mi[string(mt) =~ /^\s*CPU\s*$/]/mv[string(moid) =~ /^\s*TT\s*$/]/r} => sub { $_->set_text('30') },
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
);
$t->parse( $data );
$t->print;

__DATA__
<root>
<mi>
    <mt>CPU </mt>
    <mv>
          <moid> </moid>
           <r>1</r>
    </mv>
    <mv>
          <moid> TT </moid>
           <r>2</r>
    </mv>
</mi>
<mi>
    <mt>NOT CPU</mt>
    <mv>
          <moid> </moid>
           <r>1</r>
    </mv>
    <mv>
          <moid> TT </moid>
           <r>2</r>
    </mv>
</mi>
</root>
```

Outputs:

```
root>
 <mi>
   <mt>CPU </mt>
   <mv>
     <moid> </moid>
     <r>20</r>
   </mv>
   <mv>
     <moid> TT </moid>
     <r>30</r>
   </mv>
 </mi>
 <mi>
   <mt>NOT CPU</mt>
   <mv>
     <moid> </moid>
     <r>1</r>
   </mv>
   <mv>
     <moid> TT </moid>
     <r>2</r>
   </mv>
 </mi>
/root>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example:

```
<moid> </moid>
```

The node is not empty. It contains a space character.

You may be best off selecting the node using a regular expression. (Yes, XPath supports regular expressions, though they differ slightly to Perl regexps.)

Answer (score 0):

This XPath will construct the output that you asked for from your input:

```
for $mi in //mi[contains(mt, "CPU")]
return
    <mi>{
        $mi/mt,
        for $mv in $mi/mv return
            <mv>{
                $mv/moid,
                if(contains($mv/moid, "TT"))then
                    <r>30</r>
                else if(empty($mv/moid) or matches($mv/moid, "\s*"))then
                    <r>20</r>
                else
                    $mv/r
            }</mv>
    }</mi>
```